# How to fix "Attempt to invoke method on a null object reference"?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have an issue here. I'm trying to display the THX logo when it detect a certain TV model. But it gives `01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean jp.co.sharp.av.android.tvmodellibrary.ProductInformation.isThxFeature()' on a null object reference`. I think I already make the `Null` checking but still, my code doesn't working. Below is my code and it is `Spot.java` file:

```
public static void showAVMode(Context context, String AVMode) {
    mContext = context;
    spotText = getAvModeText(AVMode);
    spotType= "";
    call_Spot=3000;
    if (mContext != null) {
        spotType = mContext.getString(R.string.AVM_name);
        currentSpot = 5;
        if (view_Spot != null) {
            ImageView spotIcon = (ImageView) view_Spot.findViewById(R.id.spot_icon);
            if (mProductInformation.isThxFeature()) {
                TvLog.d(TAG, "Current Tv have THX feature");
                spotIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.set_thx);
            } else {
                TvLog.d(TAG, "Current Tv doesn't have THX feature and EnergyStar");
                spotIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            //ImageView spotIcon = (ImageView) view_Spot.findViewById(R.id.spot_icon);
            //spotIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //spotIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.set_thx);
            TvLog.d(TAG, "context is null");
        }
        show();
    } else {
        TvLog.d(TAG, "context is null");
    }
}
```

Below is logcat error:

```
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566): Process: jp.co.sharp.av.android.tvcore, PID: 2566
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean jp.co.sharp.av.android.tvmodellibrary.ProductInformation.isThxFeature()' on a null object reference
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at jp.co.sharp.av.android.tvcore.ui.view.Spot.showAVMode(Spot.java:127)
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at jp.co.sharp.av.android.tvcore.treat.base.ScreenBase$1.handleMessage(ScreenBase.java:377)
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
01-01 00:00:46.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2566):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

anyone please help solve this. `Spot.java:127` is this code: `if (mProductInformation.isThxFeature())`.

Comment: `at jp.co.sharp.av.android.tvcore.ui.view.Spot.showAVMode(Spot.java:127)`, line `127` is `null`.

Comment: First sentence in @Jason's answer is the most important... if you expect a non-null reference, then you need to make sure it's set properly. Seems like mProductInformation should be passed in as an argument to your method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't show where `mProductInformation` comes from or where it is populated.

Add some code to check if `mProductInformation` is null before you use it to call the `isThxFeature()` method.

Comment: ooh sorry. abour the `mProductInformation`, I make its declaration in `Spot.java` as `private static ProductInformation mProductInformation;`. and `isThxFeature()` is comes from `ProductInformation.java`. The code is like this:

`public boolean isThxFeature() {
        String name = getModelName();
        if(name == null) {
            TvLog.e(TAG, "isThxFeature getModelName is null");
        } else {
            if(name.equals(ModelName.UH30U.toString())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }`

Comment: @squallleonhart `mProductInformation` is still null. Nothing there that would change that.

Comment: i just edit my code from `private static ProductInformation mProductInformation;` to `private static ProductInformation mProductInformation = new ProductInformation ();`, and finally it works!!. can someone help me what is the diffenrence between those two?

Comment: @squallleonhart It's the difference between a null reference and a non-null reference. This isn't C++. Declaring a reference doesn't create an object.

Answer (score 0):

This instruction:

```
 private static ProductInformation mProductInformation;
```

is simply declaring a variable without giving him any object reference: it is by default null.

with `mProductInformation = new ProductInformation();` you dynamically create a new object (`new ProductInformation()`) and gives its address as reference to `mProductInformation` (`mProductInformation = ...`). Thus `mProductInformation` is not null anymore...